# Custom button in Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

We would like to create a custom button in the wordpress dashboard,

We want this button to hold our pages we create for clients,

Because I want to keep the pages section separate from our "Client" pages

[image]

i hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really quite straight forward, just takes a bit of getting used to.

You ideally need to follow the docs:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

This will guide you in how to set up an admin menu.

```
<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>
```

Will be the code you call when creating the admin sidebar menu item, however, there are more functions for create sub menu pages under it etc.

**What I think you are looking for though, is a Custom Post Type for your clients...**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'client_posttype',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Clients' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Client' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Something similar to above will get you started.

If it's all a bit much, you can generate CPT code:

https://generatewp.com/post-type/

Then have a look at the generated code to work out what it is that you would have coded yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Test this :)

```
class options_page {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'admin_menu' ) );
    }

    function admin_menu() {
        add_menu_page( 'Clients', 'Clients Page', 'edit_posts', 'clients_page', 'my_clients', '', 24);
    }

    function  settings_page() {
        echo 'This is the page content';
    }
}

new options_page;
```